# ChoiceField doesn't display an empty label when using a tuple

Tags: python, django, django-forms

### What I'm trying to do

I'm going to be keeping data about competitions in my database. I want to be able to search the competitions by certain criteria - competition type in particular.

### About competition types

Competition types are kept in a tuple. A slightly shortened example:

```
COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Olympic Games'),
    (2, 'ISU Championships'),
    (3, 'Grand Prix Series'),
)
```

These are used in the model like so (again - this is a shortened/simplified version of the model):

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

### The search form

I don't want the fields to be required in the search form, so the form is defined like this:

```
class CompetitionSearchForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES,required=False)
```

### The problem

I'd like the select widget in ChoiceField to display an empty label, but I don't get one. Any help with this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Refer to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522339/showing-please-choose-in-a-djangos-select-widget) as well.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've found a solution that works the way I want it to without violating the DRY principle. Not very clean, but it'll have to do I suppose.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) choices don't have to be a tuple:

> Finally, note that choices can be any
>   iterable object -- not necessarily a
>   list or tuple. This lets you construct
>   choices dynamically. But if you find
>   yourself hacking choices to be
>   dynamic, you're probably better off
>   using a proper database table with a
>   ForeignKey. choices is meant for
>   static data that doesn't change much,
>   if ever.

So the solution I'm going with for the moment is:

```
COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES = [
     (1, 'Olympic Games'),
     (2, 'ISU Championships'),
     (3, 'Grand Prix Series'),
]

COMP_TYPE_CHOICES_AND_EMPTY = [('','All')] + COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES
```

And then:

```
class CompetitionSearchForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COMP_TYPE_CHOICES_AND_EMPTY, required=False)
```

The model stays the same as it was.

Comment: from django.db.models.fields import BLANK_CHOICE_DASH

Comment: COMP_TYPE_CHOICES_AND_EMPTY = tuple(BLANK_CHOICE_DASH + list(COMP_TYPE_CHOICES))

Answer (score 33):

I tried both Monika's and Evgeniy's solutions with no success, but Monika has a good point in that the choices do not need to be tuples. Therefore, the easiest (and DRYest) solution is to simply do what Django does already in the Model Field. Simply add the blank choice and the tuples together after converting them to a list:

```
from django.db.models.fields import BLANK_CHOICE_DASH

...

type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH + list(COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES), required=False)
```

Answer (score 10):

Better choice is to update field choices in form **init** method

```
COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Olympic Games'),
    (2, 'ISU Championships'),
    (3, 'Grand Prix Series'),
)


class CompetitionSearchForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES,required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompetitionSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['type'].choices.insert(0, ('','---------' ) )
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the documentation:

> Either an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field, or a callable that returns such an iterable. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/)

So, you can simple:

```
sample_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('', '---'),) + Model.YOUR_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try adding `blank=True` to the model fields (assuming that's the behavior you want), then changing the form to a ModelForm and removing the field definitions. Note that any fields for which you set `blank=True` won't be required when validating *or saving* the model. Again, this may not be what you want but if it is it'll allow Django to take care of a few things automatically.

Otherwise just change your `COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES` to:

```
COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('', '---------'),
    ('1', 'Olympic Games'),
    ('2', 'ISU Championships'),
    ('3', 'Grand Prix Series'),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is useful (it didn't occur to me that you could define the value as '' - so I've learnt something :)). But unfortunately it's not the answer I'm looking for either...
blank=True is definitely not what I want and changing the tuple like you suggest has a couple of drawbacks:
a) It means I have two '---------' options in the admin now
b) If, for example, I decide I want the empty label in the search form, but don't want it in an add competition form then I'm screwed basically.

Answer (score 6):

Just a small change to [Evgeniy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765757/choicefield-doesnt-display-an-empty-label-when-using-a-tuple-am-i-doing-someth/2216679#2216679) that checks if the blank alternative is not already added.

Without the check (at least when running the builtin runserver) one extra empty label is added for each page reload.

```
COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Olympic Games'),
    (2, 'ISU Championships'),
    (3, 'Grand Prix Series'),
)

class CompetitionSearchForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES,required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompetitionSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.fields['type'].choices[0][0] == '':
            self.fields['type'].choices.insert(0, ('','---------' ) )
```

Comment: +1 for checking the existing blank. Not sure if this is because things have changed since 2010, but I had to use self.fields['type'].widget.choices

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ModelForm if you are already have model class?

Best solution:

**forms.py**

```
class CompetitionSearchForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Competition
```

**models.py**

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES, default=COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES[0][0], blank=True)
```

You can set **blank=False** to remove empty_label from list

Comment: Because this was a search form - I would have to override a lot so there would be no required or unique validation. Otherwise every time somebody would try to search, django would say a competion like that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

*A little late to the party..*

How about not modifying the choices at all and just handling it with a widget?

```
from django.db.models import BLANK_CHOICE_DASH

class EmptySelect(Select):
    empty_value = BLANK_CHOICE_DASH[0]
    empty_label = BLANK_CHOICE_DASH[1]

    @property
    def choices(self):
        yield (self.empty_value, self.empty_label,)
        for choice in self._choices:
            yield choice

    @choices.setter
    def choices(self, val):
        self._choices = val
```

Then just call it:

```
class CompetitionSearchForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES,required=False, widget=EmptySelect)
```

This is what you end up with:

```
print(CompetitionSearchForm().as_p())
<p>
    <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
    <input id="id_name" name="name" type="text" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="id_type">Type:</label>
    <select id="id_type" name="type">
        <option value="" selected="selected">------</option>
        <option value="1">Olympic Games</option>
        <option value="2">ISU Championships</option>
        <option value="3">Grand Prix Series</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Javier's answer.

Instead of customizing the signature of **choices** which would fail in [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) checking, its better to use a custom property and change it only in the display options.

```
class EmptySelect(Select):
    @property
    def custom_choices(self):
        yield BLANK_CHOICE_DASH[0]
        yield from self.choices

    def optgroups(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        """Return a list of optgroups for this widget."""
        groups = []
        has_selected = False
        # START_CHANGES
        for index, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(self.custom_choices):
            # END_CHANGES
            if option_value is None:
                option_value = ""

            subgroup = []
            if isinstance(option_label, (list, tuple)):
                group_name = option_value
                subindex = 0
                choices = option_label
            else:
                group_name = None
                subindex = None
                choices = [(option_value, option_label)]
            groups.append((group_name, subgroup, index))

            for subvalue, sublabel in choices:
                selected = str(subvalue) in value and (not has_selected or self.allow_multiple_selected)
                has_selected |= selected
                subgroup.append(
                    self.create_option(
                        name,
                        subvalue,
                        sublabel,
                        selected,
                        index,
                        subindex=subindex,
                        attrs=attrs,
                    )
                )
                if subindex is not None:
                    subindex += 1
        return groups
```

And use this widget anywhere like:

```
class CompetitionSearchForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COMPETITION_TYPE_CHOICES,required=False, widget=EmptySelect)
```

Note: Don't use **type** as a filed name as it's python built-in keyword instead name it something else for good practice.