# Showing "Please choose:" in a Django's `Select` widget

Tags: python, django, validation, forms

I'm making a Django form and using `ChoiceField` which generates a `<select>` box with the different options. I would like that `<select>` box's first option to be "Please choose:", and that if the user submits the form without choosing, he'll get an error.

What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like Django doesn't have built-in support for such a request. You can achieve it by subclassing `ChoiceField` and making it accept a `blank_choice` argument. e.g.

```
from django import forms


class ChoiceField(forms.ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.blank_choice = kwargs.pop('blank_choice', None)
        super(ChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _get_choices(self):
        return self._choices

    def _set_choices(self, value):
        choices = list(value)
        if self.blank_choice:
            choices = [('', self.blank_choice)] + choices
        self._choices = self.widget.choices = choices

    choices = property(_get_choices, _set_choices)
```

This blank choice is prepended to the normal set of choices, and is treated as an empty value. (This is why I've used `None` as the value associated with the `self.blank_choice` choice, as it's in the `django.core.validators.EMPTY_VALUES` tuple).

To use it, use this `ChoiceField` rather than the one provided by Django, and pass in a value for `blank_choice`, e.g.

```
from django import forms
from myproject.formfields import ChoiceField

NAMES = (
    ('brad', 'Brad'),
    ('sam', 'Sam'),
)

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    names = ChoiceField(choices=NAMES, blank_choice='Please choose:')
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work (Django doesn't call `_set_choices` method). Why?