# django select box

Tags: django

this is the modelform code of my django framework. As you  can see i retreive values from the database and display through an list box.

This works perfectly fine, but in the list box only the values are displayed. I need to add a word such as "select" in the list box.

```
date_value_list = MeasurementTest.objects.values_list('start_date',flat = True).distinct()
date1 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = date_value_list, widget = forms.Select, required =  True)
```

i am actually trying to add a label or help_text in the above select box. But it seems not to work.

```
date1 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = date_value_list, widget = forms.Select, required =  True,help_text="select",label = "select")
```

the above code does not seem to work. can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [empty_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label).

```
# A custom empty label
field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., empty_label="Select value")

# No empty label
field2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., empty_label=None)
```

Comment: @ashan actually it does not seems to work for my particular case. as i use ModelMultipleChoiceField.

Comment: @sankar As you mentioned in title, you need to do it in list box or in select then why you are using `ModelMultipleChoiceField`??

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons for that.

- If you set that field as `required=True` in your form
- If you set the model field as `blank=False` in your `MeasurementTest` model

In both conditions, django will realize it is a required field and will not add an `empty_label` (because that field can not be blank) even if you specified.

> Note that if a ModelChoiceField is required and has a default initial value, no empty choice is created (regardless of the value of empty_label).

[Empty label definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label)

Answer (score -1):

remove that `required=True` from the FormField.
and add `empty_label="Select"`

Similar post for your question [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765757/choicefield-doesnt-display-an-empty-label-when-using-a-tuple-am-i-doing-somet)