# Django Form ChoiceField Dropdown with empty value?

Tags: django, forms

I need some advice here. I'm trying to create a dropdown of numbers in a form and i want the first option to be nothing/blank/empty.

In my models:

```
number = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

In my form (not a modelform but a regular form) i got a Choicefield:

```
number = forms.ChoiceField(choices=adropdown, required=False)
```

and a dropdown like this:

```
adropdown = [('','')]
for y in range(1, 50):
    adropdown.append((y, y))
```

But im getting a error "invalid literal for int() with base 10:" when i try to submit the form.

How can i change this so i can have a dropdown with different numeric values but the first option is blank/empty. I've tried 0 and it works but does not look good when i list my objects i rather have it showing nothing. Do i change th modelfield to Charfield instead? Or will that make me loose some int-properties of IntegerField?

Thank you

Comment: Use empty_label instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label

Comment: Yeah seems a lot smarter. (beginner over here) Hehe.

Comment: Hmm. This gave me another error instead: "got an unexpected keyword argument 'empty_label'Request Method: GETRequest". Any ideas?

Comment: `number = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.Select(choices=adropdown ), empty_label="(Empty)")` should work

Comment: Nope. Still the same error.. :/

Comment: Have a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765757/choicefield-doesnt-display-an-empty-label-when-using-a-tuple-am-i-doing-somet

Comment: Thank you. I've been looking at the thread and trying many different solutions. Still can't get it to work. So frustrating.